# Framer Motion - Different Animations in Mapped elements

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am trying to loop over some data and map them to an animated SVG morph but every component instance has different paths.

Framer motion seems to animate them exactly the same even though there paths are different. Any idea how do I make the animations between elements different instead of all of them matching?

Here's a [codesandbox describing the issue](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mkhatib/laqta.photography/draft/epic-greider?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clabpft7y0008l1e74yhudr4a%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522%252Fpages%252Findex.tsx%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clabz9izv00103b6htnvpwth3%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clabpgdws00993b6h7u1bmj67%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clabpgc47005v3b6hyjbsyud8%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D). Notice that the repeated Dog blob is running through the exact paths animations, even though paths passed to <animated.path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `Blob` component for the `motion.path` element, perhaps the `d: paths` should be `d: gallery.paths`?

Otherwise it seems that the paths to be animated for both `Blob` would be the original `const paths` without randomized by `randomItem.multiple()`, hence the exactly same morphing animations.

**Update**

For the second issue, it seems that both `clipPath` share the same `id`, which is a global value, unlike the scoped `key`. This resulted in just the first clip path was used, and is solved by giving each of them unique `id`.

With this fix I can see 2 different morphing animations on my end now, so hopefully this solved all the problems.

```
        <g>
          <defs>
            <clipPath id={`shape-${gallery.key}`}>
              <LayoutGroup id={gallery.key}>
                <motion.path
                  layoutId={gallery.key}
                  style={{
                    fill: "#9565c8",
                    transform: "translate(200px, 200px)",
                  }}
                  animate={{
                    d: gallery.paths,
                    repeatCount: Infinity,
                    autoReverse: true,
                  }}
                  transition={{
                    repeat: Infinity,
                    ease: "easeInOut",
                    duration: gallery.paths.length,
                    reverse: true,
                    repeatType: "reverse",
                    bounce: true,
                    bounceStiffness: 10,
                  }}
                />
              </LayoutGroup>
            </clipPath>
          </defs>
          <image
            style={{ position: "absolute", top: 100, left: 100 }}
            clipPath={`url(#shape-${gallery.key})`}
            xlinkHref={gallery.image}
          />
        </g>
```

Comment: You're right that was wrong. But updating it still shows the same behavior. Were you able to see something different in the codesandbox?

Comment: Let me have a look too, but I can't seem to fork and test it as it is in read-only mode

Comment: I updated the link in the original question, it should hopefully let you fork the project now

Comment: @mkhatib Thanks, I was able to fork and addressed the second issue I think. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: @mkhatib No problem glad it works for you!